# How to reduce time of script execution with FormApp...getResponses()?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-forms

The Email collection function built into the form is in the Text format. We have a lot of employees filling out this form, so it would be more convenient to choose from a drop-down list than to manually enter an email for each employee. The built-in function of collecting emails does not allow using the Dropdown list question type, so I had to disable it and send the response to the email using a script.

In addition, when you select one of the options (Transfer) in the form, you need to insert an additional correction row with data. This is also done by the script.

[image]

The script works fine, but unfortunately, its execution time reaches 45 seconds. I think this is abnormally large.

**Updated code:**

```
var FORM_ID = '#####';
var SHEET_NAME = 'Operations';

function sendFormToEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  console.time('section10'); // 25579ms
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  console.timeEnd('section10');
  
  // Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
  var form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);
  
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var i = formResponses.length - 1;
  var formResponse = formResponses[i]; // Last item
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  
  var length = itemResponses.length;
  Logger.log("length = " + length);

  var emailTo = itemResponses[0].getResponse();  // Returns the email if given
  var cp = itemResponses[1].getResponse();  // Counterparty
  var subject = "Input form: "+ cp;
  var datePay = itemResponses[2].getResponse();  // Date of the operation
  var dateAccept = itemResponses[3].getResponse();  // Date of acceptance
  var sum = itemResponses[4].getResponse() ;  // Amount
  var what = itemResponses[5].getResponse();  // Operation type

  var comm =  "Correction " + itemResponses[length - 1].getResponse(); // Last response
  var sum_1 = parseFloat(sum.replace(/,/, '.')) * (-1);  // Amount * (-1)
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var textBody = "Operation: " + timestamp + ";\n";

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    var resp = itemResponse.getResponse();
    textBody += itemResponse.getItem().getTitle() + "=" + resp + ";\n";
  }

  if (what == 'Transfer') { // If the transfer between your accounts
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.insertRowBefore(lr);
    var values = [datePay, dateAccept, "", sum_1, "", "", "", "", comm, "", "", "", what, timestamp, "", "", ""];
    Logger.log(values);
    console.time('section12'); // 19449ms
    sheet.getRange(lr, 2, 1, 17).setValues([values]);
    console.timeEnd('section12')
  }
  
  if(emailTo !== undefined){
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody);
  }
}
```

At first I thought it was the large size of the acceptance sheet (about 13 thousand rows). I created a copy of the table, reduced it to several dozen rows, but the speed did not increase much.
Then I deleted the answers from the form (there were just under 9000 of them) - the same thing, I didn't get much performance gain.

Anyone have any ideas how to change the script algorithm to improve its performance?

===

**Conclusions**

Thanks to @TheMaster for the help with `console.time()`. Thanks to this tool I found bottlenecks in the code. More precisely, the code works well, but it's about the structure of the spreadsheets system with which the code interacts. The structure needs to be optimized.
There was also an idea addressed, probably, to Google developers. It would be great if there was a tool that visually (graphically) displays the relationships between spreadsheets and sheets that make up a single system. Perhaps with some kind of numerical characteristics that reflect, for example, the interaction time between its blocks. This would make it possible to quickly eliminate such bottlenecks in the system and improve it.

Comment: Have you tried `appendRow`?

Comment: Yes, at first I tried using appendRow, but it inserts a row at the bottom of the sheet. The next input through the form inserts data above it and as a result all the corrective rows are at the bottom. It is desirable that the correcting row is next to the row that it is correcting. Therefore, I had to abandon the appendrow.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for the idea. I also removed the check from the loop, did `if (what == 'Transfer') {... setValues...}`.
Unfortunately, it did not help: time ~ 40 sec.

Comment: Could you add a update of your script to your post by [edit]ing it?

Comment: @TheMaster I did it.

Comment: Try adding `console.time('section1')` and `console.timeEnd('section1')` at various sections of your code to figure out  which section takes the most time...  If you figure out the section of code, try figuring out the exact line by adding subsections within that section

Comment: Also, what about a new dummy form with the same number of items  and a new spreadsheet with a dozen rows?

Comment: Thanks for the tool!
Duration 41.512 s
`console.time('section10'); // 25579ms
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
console.timeEnd('section10');
...
console.time('section12'); // 19449ms
sheet.getRange(lr, 2, 1, 17).setValues([values]);
console.timeEnd('section12') `
It looks like it's not the form, but the sheet? But what to do next?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223053/discussion-between-boris-baublys-and-themaster).

Comment: [Edit] to add this information. Your sheet is probably bloated. Delete sheets, delete empty  cells  at the bottom and right of each sheet

Comment: Yes, there are no empty rows at the bottom and empty columns on the right, I keep track of this. Perhaps the reason is that the spreadsheet is overloaded. It has 30 sheets, all of them have a bunch of formulas, most of them are related to other spreadsheets. The structure of the system will probably have to be changed.

Comment: I made a copy of the spreadsheet, left 9 sheets out of 30 and the duration of the script was reduced to 5.477 s.

Comment: Consider adding how you debugged and  your findings as a answer. As you said, it's probably due to import* formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Investigation:

- Pinpointing the issue is done using `console.time()` and `console.timeEnd()` of each section of code and calculating the time taken by reachl each section of code.

#### Issue:

As  discussed in [the question comment chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353960/how-to-reduce-time-of-script-execution-with-formapp-getresponses#comment113807184_64353960), This is due to a bloated spreadsheet with many sheets and import formulas. This caused more time to get the exact sheet and to use setValues:

```
console.time('section10'); // 25579ms 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME); 
console.timeEnd('section10');
//....
console.time('section12'); // 19449ms 
sheet.getRange(lr, 2, 1, 17).setValues([values]);
console.timeEnd('section12')
```

#### Possible solutions:

- Reduce number of sheets
- Reduce interconnected spreadsheets (=`import*` formulas)
- Delete empty rows  on the bottom and empty columns on the right of each sheet.